# Stuck on last step of grapejuice installation

Tags: python, roblox

I was trying to install [grapejuice](https://gitlab.com/brinkervii/grapejuice).

I was following this [guide](https://gitlab.com/brinkervii/grapejuice/-/wikis/Installing-from-source/Ubuntu-18.04-and-similar) and at the last step—(re-)running `python3.7 ./install.py`—I encountered this stack trace:
[image: stack trace]

Prior to the said stack trace, initially running `python3.7 ./install.py` returned an error saying it doesn't recognize `python3.7` as a command therefore it suggested to install **python-minimal** by running `sudo apt install python-minimal`, which I was able to do without any issue.

#### Edit

I tried to install the missing `setuptools` module as suggested by **Dipendra Pant** in the comments.

I'm unfamiliar with Python so I was not sure how to do it but here's what I did:

1. I tried to check if `pip` was a recognized command by typing "pip" in the terminal; It wasn't, therefore running `sudo apt install python-pip` was suggested. I ran the command and pip was installed successfully.
2. I then ran `pip install setuptools` in the directory of my local copy of grapejuice:
   [image]
3. After installing setuptools. I tried `python3.7 ./install.py` again:
   [image]
   It returned the same error.

#### Edit #2

I tried the answer of **alluraendless**—running `python ./install.py` or `python3 ./install.py` instead of `python3.7 ./install.py` but still no luck.

`python ./install.py` returned this stack trace:
[image]

I think this is a syntax error presumably because `file=sys.stderr` is a statement where the argument list of `print()` expected an expression?? or possibly, the `python` command is using a version of python that doesn't recognize that syntax??

`python3 ./install.py` returned this error:
[image]

This is so because as mentioned in this [section](https://gitlab.com/brinkervii/grapejuice/-/wikis/Installing-from-source/Ubuntu-18.04-and-similar#add-the-deadsnakes-repository) of the [guide](https://gitlab.com/brinkervii/grapejuice/-/wikis/Installing-from-source/Ubuntu-18.04-and-similar) I mentioned above:

> Grapejuice requires at least Python3.7...

Comment: Have you tried "pip install setuptools" ? Normally No module found means the package has not been installed on your device :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon their discord and found the answer.

Apparently I missed this [step](https://gitlab.com/brinkervii/grapejuice/-/wikis/Installing-from-source/Ubuntu-18.04-and-similar#installing-grapejuice-dependencies) in the installation: *Installing Grapejuice dependencies*. The command in this step also installs `python3.7`, which was initially unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `python3.7 ./install.py` to :

```
python ./install.py
```

or

```
python3 ./install.py
```

Then everything will be fine.